# Android Settings - inverse dependency

Tags: android, xml, dependencies, settings

I have a primary Boolean setting that when true would make one child active, but when it is false child a would be disabled and child B would be active.

ie;

```
if (ParentSetting == true) activate childSettingB elseIf(ParentSetting == false) activate childSettingB
```

I know how to have dependency in the xml tags, but is it possible to have an inverse relationship towards a specific child setting?

thank you

ps. I want to do it in XML if possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this purely in xml.

Using android:disableDependentsState="true" on the parent (preference which is being depended on) will allow you to inverse the dependency but it will both the child settings. This is not what you want.
[disableDependentsState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html#attr_android:disableDependentsState)

Only way is to do it is programmatically. You probably know how to do that already.

```
SwitchPreference dependee = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("dependee");
dependent2.setEnabled(!dependee.isChecked());
dependee.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue){
            boolean isEnabled = ((Boolean) newValue).booleanValue();
            dependent2.setEnabled(!isEnabled);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the `android:disableDependentsState="true"` in the CheckBoxPreference

For Example:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="cb_key"
        android:title="@string/stop_service"
        android:summaryOn="On
        android:summaryOff="Off"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:disableDependentsState="true" />
   <Preference
        android:key="pref_key"
        android:title="pref_title"
        android:summary="pref_summary"
        android:dependency="cb_key" />
```

this way the Preference will be disabled when the CheckBoxPreference is ON "true" and vice versa.